# How to remove other html tags except p tag on Paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy-paste, tinymce-4

I am having a little trouble with my inline text editor. it is simple user has permission to copy paste on the textarea div. no problem with that. but i dont want let them paste html with images, and div elements.

I have used

```
valid_elements: "p,br,b,i,strong,em",
```

it removes the style of `p tags` content.

to do this but this is not the solution according to my requirements.

and i also tried with `paste_postprocess` but it didn't do anything with latest version of tinymce.

and i have also tried many solutions which are already posted in this community. but none of them work for me because i am using the latest version `tinymce 4.0.26`.

i know i can prevent copy paste by disabling right click. but that will not be a good idea.

Is there any way to filter only `p tag` with `style` from html content?

So if anybody has worked `on copy paste` with the latest versions of `tinymce`.

Please help.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. Do you want to not allow `img` and `div` elements, or do you want to not allow `style` attributes on `p` tags?

Comment: I dont want to allow `img` and `div` elements. If user pasted these all `img,div,p` then i only need `p` along with its `style`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell TinyMCE what attributes to keep when using the `valid_elements` option. For example, using your previous `valid_elements` list, you might do something like this:

```
valid_elements: "p[style],br,b,i,strong,em"
```

This tells TinyMCE to only keep the tags listed and to keep any `style` attributes defined for `p` tags. Alternatively, you can also include all attributes for a specific element by doing this:

```
valid_elements: "p[*],br,b,i,strong,em"
```

Again, this tells TinyMCE to keep all of the tags listed, but for the `p` tag, keep every attribute defined.

For more information on the syntax of this `valid_elements` selector, check out [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the `Bad condition is`: when i pasted the content in editor with `img,div,p` then after pasting content it shows all the element inside the box (AFTER PASTING ON EDITOR). And `GOOD condition is`: when i get the content of editor it gives me only `p tag` with its style (Thats what i am looking for). But i am wondering if it shows only the `p` tag after pasting content inside the editor.

Comment: I see, try using the [Paste plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste). It says it's specifically for MS Word, but I have a feeling that if users are pasting in explicit HTML code, it will handle that the same. Look at using the `paste_word_valid_elements` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Bad condition is: when I pasted the content in editor with img, div, p
>   then after pasting content it shows all the element inside the box
>   (AFTER PASTING ON EDITOR)

I just followed to the whole process paste->savetext. Issue was `tinymce` does nothing when pasting the content but when I call the `tinymce` function

`tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();`

It gives me pure content without `img,div`. So I thought why not to do that process `on paste`

So I just simply added this code in tinymce `setup` section:

```
setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on('paste',function(e){
           setTimeout(function(){
               var textContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
                   tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent(textContent.trim());
           },200);  
        });
   }
```

and now everything working fine.

and Thanks @Nate Kibler for your help.